# How to get varable from function to another function

Tags: node.js, express, backend

This is a simple express server

```
app.post('/bg-login', (req, res) => {
  var email1 = req.body.email;
  const path = './Databases/User/' + email1 + '.json';

  if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    try {
      // Note that jsonString will be a <Buffer> since we did not specify an
      // encoding type for the file. But it'll still work because JSON.parse() will
      // use <Buffer>.toString().
    } catch (err) {
      return;
    }
    user1 = fs.readFileSync('./Databases/User/1.json');
    user = JSON.parse(user1);
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login-e1');
  }

  if (user.password == req.body.password) {
    console.log('login sescesful for: ' + user.email + ' ' + logedin);
    logedin = 1;
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
    console.log(logedin);
  } else {
    res.redirect('/login-e2');
  }
  return 'user';
});

app.get('/dashboard', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello ' + user);
});
```

now if I run the code it returns the error user is undefined, how would I transfer data from "bg-login" to "dashboard". I tried puting "global." in front of variables, but then insed of the value of variables it outputted {Object object}

Comment: An API like this should be stateless. You shouldn't store the user in a state in the API. Instead, the frontend should send which user is sending the request.  Preferably with a JWT token.

PS: 'sescesful' is spelled as 'successful'

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this. I left you some comments to improrve your code.

```
app.post('/bg-login', (req, res) => {
  const email = req.body.email; // You need to validate the email (if it exists, if it is a valid email, its length, etc.)
  const password = req.body.password // You need to validate the password (if it exists, if it is a valid password, its length, etc.)
  const path = './Databases/User/' + email + '.json';

  if (fs.existsSync(path)) {
    try {
      const dbPath = fs.readFileSync('./Databases/User/1.json');
      const user = JSON.parse(dbPath);

      if (user.password === password) { // When checking for equality, use === instead of ==
        console.log(`Successful login for ${email}.`);
        logedin = 1; // what is this for?

        res.redirect('/dashboard');
      } else {
        // Wrong password
        res.redirect('/login-e2');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return;
    }
   
  } else {
    // File does not exist
    res.redirect('/login-e1');
  }
});

// Rest of code...
```